Is the integral a convex function?
So if we have a measurable space $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$, let us consider $L_1(\mu)$, the space of integrable functions $h:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then, the mapping $L_1(\mu)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
$$h\mapsto \int_{\mathcal{X}} h d\mu$$
is linear and hence both convex and concave.
The same should hold for non-negative, measurable $h:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\} $ since for these the integral is as well linear and hence the mapping is convex.
But what happens if  I have a convex, non-negative, measurable function $g:\mathcal{Y}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ and $f$ is now a measurable function $f:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow\mathcal{Y}$ and then we consider the convexity of $$f\mapsto \int_{\mathcal{X}}g(f(x))d\mu(x).$$
So there is a proposition that says that the composition of a linear, non-decreasing function and a convex function is convex. Now granted, the integral is also monotone, i.e., non-decreasing but I think I can prove that the above mapping is convex without requiring the monotonicity ($\lambda\in (0,1)$):
$$\int g(\lambda f_1+(1-\lambda)f_2)d\mu \leq \int (\lambda g(f_1)+(1-\lambda)g(f_2))d\mu\\=\lambda\int g(f_1)d\mu+(1-\lambda)\int g(f_2)d\mu$$
Hence the mapping is convex and I haven't made use of the non-decreasingness of the integral. So what is going on here?

I don't understand what $\lambda f_1+(1-\lambda)f_2$ is: the codomain of your $f$-s is $\mathcal Y$.

@Mittens thanks for your correction. I have updated it. Yes I know of Jensen's inequality how can I use it here to show convexity of the integral?

@SassatelliGiulio hmm yeah you are right actually. But how would I be able to show convexity otherwise? I mean, this is the way how convexity is being shown usually... So would I need to have that $\mathcal{Y}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ or sth for this to work? More generally, is convexity only defined on the reals and on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and not on more general spaces?

@guest1: Presumably $\mathcal{Y}$ a convex set in some topological vector space or on the real line. The issue is that if $\mathcal{Y}$ is contained in an infinite dimensional topological vector space, measurability of $g\circ f$ is not guaranteed.

@guest1: Even if $\mathcal{Y}$ were a convex set in euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ and effective domain of a convex function $g$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, the domain of the map $G: f\mapsto\int g\circ f,d\mu$ (i.e. the set of measurable functions $f$ in $\mathcal{Y}$ such that $g\circ f\in L_1$) may not be convex and thus $G$ would not be convex. I think you need more specificificity and less generality. On last thing, if you suppose $f$ is nonnegative, why do you write $f:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\cup{\pm\infty}$. It is confusing, just drop the $-\infty$.

@Mittens thanks again, but where does my above proof in my question then break?
And the other question is: Why does the domain of $G$ need to be convex? Can a convex function never have a non-convex domain?

@guest1: The measurability of $g \circ f$ You did not make any assumptions on $\mathcal{Y}$, too general. Also, you may want to restrict yourself to functions $f$ rich that $g\circ f$ are $\mu$-integrable... I saw your edit, is $g$ also nonnegative? or proper convex ?

@guest1: The construction you are sort of describing in a very general setting is used in analysis in a more specific setting. See Orlicz spaces. Here is a posting that  construct such spaces. the main ingredients are a convex function with some additional properties that are amenable to integration.

@Mittens thanks again. So if I manage to make $g(f)$ measurable, then my proof above works and the mapping from $f$ to $\int g(f)$ is convex?
So in my setting that I am interested in, $g$ is a non-negative measurable convex function (mapping to the non-negative extended reals) and $f$ is only assumed to be measurable. I.e., $f$ is not non-negative or anything, also not assumed to be convex. And neither of them is assumed to be integrable only measurable.

@Mittens I have edited my question since the it may have been confusing that in the introduction of my question I called the function also $f$ but it had different assumptions than the function $f$ that I use later on in my question.

@Mittens So what I now not understand from your comments is, that in your second last comment you said that my proof of the convexity fails due to the measurability of $g(f)$, but earlier you said that even if $\mathcal{Y}$ was a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ the convexity may fail due to the domain....

@Mittens sorry to ping you again but could you maybe comment on my questions to lift my confusion a bit?

You are definitely using the monotonicity of the integral here:
$$ \int g(\lambda f_1+(1-\lambda)f_2)d\mu \leq \int (\lambda g(f_1)+(1-\lambda)g(f_2))d\mu. $$
You have the above inequality by the monotonicity of the integral, since
$$ g(\lambda f_1+(1-\lambda)f_2) \leq \lambda g(f_1)+(1-\lambda)g(f_2). $$

@LorenzoPompili thanks for your answer! Can you maybe also comment on the measurability argument by Mittens?
